# Remove screen from window

Tags: windows, screens

I've got an American Craftsman 70 series double hung window and I'm trying to remove the screen.  It is a full screen, and the only mechanisms on the screen are in the corners as shown in the picture below.

I've pushed, pulled, slid, and prodded but I can't get the screen out.  Anyone know how to take out the screen?

[image: window screen]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That type of handle usually means the the screen is "spring loaded" into the channel opposite where those handles are. It should slide "across" (like a sliding glass door) until the edge near the handle is free and you can then pull it inward. Or, in some cases, outward, per comment.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick.  You have to push outward instead of inward though.